# Get JSON as input in apache flink

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to receive and access JSON data from a Kafka Topic in Flink. What works is, producing data, send it to a Kafka Topic und receive it in Flink as String. But I want to access the data in an object-oriented way (e.g. extract a specific atrribute from every message)?

Therefore I have a Kafka Producer which sends data (e.g. every 1s) to a Kafka Topic:

```
ObjectMapper test = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode jNode= test.createObjectNode();
jNode.put("LoPos", longPos)
    .put("LaPos", latPos)
    .put("Timestamp", timestamp.toString());

ProducerRecord<String, ObjectNode> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, ObjectNode>(topicName, jNode);
        producer.send(rec);
```

so the JSON data looks like this:

```
{"LoPos":10.5,"LaPos":2.5,"Timestamp":"2022-10-31 12:45:19.353"}
```

What works is, receiving the data and print it as string:

```
        DataStream<String> input =
        env.fromSource(
                KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                        .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                        .setTopics(topicName)
                        .build(),
                WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                "kafka-source");
```

Print the data as string:

```
        DataStream<String> parsed = input.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;
            @Override
            public String map(String value) {
                System.out.println(value);
                return "test";
```

How can I receive the data in Flink and access it in an object-oriented way (e.g. extract LoPos from every message)? Which approach would you recommend? I tried it with JSONValueDeserializationSchema, but without success...

Thanks!

**Update1:**
I updated to Flink 1.16 to use JsonDeserializationSchema.
Then I created a Flink Pojo Event like this:

```
public class Event {
public double LoPos;
public double LaPos;
public Timestamp timestamp;

public Event() {}

public Event(final double LoPos, final double LaPos, final Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.LaPos=LaPos;
    this.LoPos=LoPos;
    this.timestamp=timestamp;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(LaPos);
}
```

}

To read the JSON data, I implemented the following:

```
                KafkaSource<Event> source = KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
                    .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(Event.class))
                    .setTopics("testTopic2")
                    .build();
            
            DataStream<Event> test=env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "test");
            
            System.out.println(source.toString());
            System.out.println(test.toString());
            
            //test.sinkTo(new PrintSink<>());               
            test.print();
            env.execute();
```

So I would expect, when using source.toString() the value of LaPos is getting returned. But all I get is:

```
org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource@510f3d34
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic is covered in [one of the recipes in the Immerok Apache Flink Cookbook](https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/deserializing-json-from-kafka-to-apache-flink-pojo/).

In the examples below, I'm assuming `Event` is a Flink POJO.

With Flink 1.15 or earlier, you should use a custom deserializer:

```java
KafkaSource<Event> source =
    KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .setTopics(TOPIC)
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new EventDeserializationSchema())
        .build();
```

The deserializer can be something like this:

```java
public class EventDeserializationSchema extends AbstractDeserializationSchema<Event> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private transient ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    /**
     * For performance reasons it's better to create on ObjectMapper in this open method rather than
     * creating a new ObjectMapper for every record.
     */
    @Override
    public void open(InitializationContext context) {
        // JavaTimeModule is needed for Java 8 data time (Instant) support
        objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    /**
     * If our deserialize method needed access to the information in the Kafka headers of a
     * KafkaConsumerRecord, we would have implemented a KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema instead of
     * extending AbstractDeserializationSchema.
     */
    @Override
    public Event deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(message, Event.class);
    }
}
```

We've made this easier in Flink 1.16, where we've added a proper `JsonDeserializationSchema` you can use:

```java
KafkaSource<Event> source =
    KafkaSource.<Event>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .setTopics(TOPIC)
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(Event.class))
        .build();
```

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you please check my Update1 in the initial post? I updated to Flink 1.16, wrote a Flink POJO and set the JsonDeserializationSchema for the KafkaSource. But I am not able to access the data of the JSON as I would expect.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. `test.print` should print a stream of Events, with each one printing LaPos. As you've seen, `toString` on a Source or a DataStream doesn't do anything very useful -- that's normal.